# How to correctly "require" in application.css? (skeleton framework)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, frameworks, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am attempting to use the skeleton-rails CSS framework in my app.  I have some containers and a list nav in my `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` that I'm trying to style.  I've followed the instructions at the skeleton git repo, which include adding `gem 'skeleton-rails` to the `Gemfile`.  Then I ran `bundle install` and `rails g skeleton:install` from my app home directory.  As the instructions indicated, this added the following to my `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`:

```
= require base

= require layout

= require skeleton
```

However, in my file everything is commented out, and the above lines have asterisks (*) in front of them.  I've tried ending the comment block before the `require`s, removing the asterisks and the equal signs, etc, but I'm still not seeing the changes I should see from the skeleton styling when I reload my page.  Is there something I'm missing?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I backed up and just left everything the way it was, without uncommenting anything (i.e. without moving the location of the last `*/`).  Now it seems to work.  So the requires work from within the comment block in application.css?

Answer (score 0):

Try *gem list* to see if Skeleton installed.

[Also, check out how the manifest file pulls in resources in Rails here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives).

Comment: Skeleton is in the gem list. It was just a misunderstanding on my part about the use of those asterisks and equal signs.  The link cleared it up.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Per RailsGuides the `require`s are supposed to remain within the comment block and keep their asterisks and equal signs.